# Optimization of file read in C#

Tags: c#, data-structures

I have a requirement to copy a file, parse it's contents removing the line breaks, and the splitting the content along the pipes, and then storing the resulting string[] off in the database. My files could get as large as 65000 valid records each, and so performance is essential.

Below is what I currently have. Problem is it is extremely slow( 3 hours to process 65000 lines). I would appreciate any help with improving optimizing this piece so my runs can be significantly faster.

```
public void ReadFileLinesIntoRows()
    {
        try
        {
            using (var reader = new TextFieldParser(FileName))
            {
                reader.HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes = false;
                reader.TextFieldType = FieldType.Delimited;
                reader.SetDelimiters("|");
                String[] currentRow;
                while (!reader.EndOfData)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        currentRow = reader.ReadFields();
                        int rowcount = currentRow.Count();
                        //if it is less than what you need, pad it.  
                        if (rowcount < 190)
                        {
                            Array.Resize<string>(ref currentRow, 190);  
                            rows.Add(currentRow);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            rows.Add(currentRow);
                        }
                    }
                    catch (MalformedLineException mex)
                    {
                        unreadlines.Add(reader.ErrorLine);//continue afterwards
                    } 
                }
                this.TotalRowCount  = rows.Count();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            throw ex;
        }
    }

   public void cleanfilecontent(String tempfilename, Boolean? HeaderIncluded)
    {
        try
        { 
            //remove the empty lines in the file 
            using (var sr = new StreamReader(tempfilename))
            {
                // Write new file
                using (var sw = new StreamWriter(CleanedCopy))
                {
                    using (var smove = new StreamWriter(duptempfileremove))
                    {
                        string line;

                        Boolean skippedheader = false;
                        while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                        {
                            // Look for text to remove
                            if (line.Contains("----------------------------------"))
                            { 
                                smove.Write(line);
                            }
                            else if (HeaderIncluded.HasValue && HeaderIncluded.Value==true && ! skippedheader)
                            {
                                smove.Write(line);
                                skippedheader = true;
                            }
                            else if(skippedheader)
                            {
                                // Keep lines that does not match
                                sw.WriteLine(line);
                            } 
                        }
                        smove.Flush();
                    }
                    sw.Flush();
                }
                sr.Close();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            throw ex;
        }

    }
```

Comment: What does your `TextFieldParser` look like?

Comment: TextFieldParser lib is found in Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO

Answer (score 0):

65000 records isn't all that big. If you have sufficient memory, I will suggest read the whole file to memory, perform your parsing and construct your row and use batch insert to commit the data to DB. This will be the fastest! I suspect most of your 3 hours is spent in inserting database record one at a time to the database.

Comment: That is what I have working right now and it is really slow. I am trying to find ways to optimize the reading and parsing aspect, and maybe also the database aspect if possible.

Comment: Becareful that calling one single submit/commit method in EF or data adapter does not equate to a single batch insert. Under the hood typically this is executed as multiple single insert statement which will kill your performance. Have a look at this http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/354094/Bulk-Insert-in-NET-applications-Part-1

Comment: You should profile at at very least debug and work out where the bottleneck is. Is it at the load/read of file, or at the commit of the records

Comment: The commit for each record seems to go fairly at the same rate and from debugs of the stored procs that handle porting the data to the various tables, I think that is not where the problem really is.